# Phusion Passenger: Using OOB work to exit a process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Phusion Passenger version: 5.0.29

I've read the documentation about [Passenger's OOB (Out-of-Band)](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/out_of_band_work.html) feature and would like to use it to make a decision out-of-band on whether a process should exit or not. If the process has to exit, then at the end of the OOB work, the process calls `raise SystemExit`

We've managed to get this working where the process exits and then Passenger spins up a new process later to handle the new incoming requests. But, we're seeing occasional 502s with the following lines in the passenger log.

```
[ 2019-03-27 22:25:13.3855 31726/7f78b6c02700 age/Cor/Con/InternalUtils.cpp:112 ]: [Client 1-10] Sending
502 response: application did not send a complete response
[ 2019-03-27 22:25:13.3859 31726/7f78b6201700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:819 ]: Checking whether to disconnect
long-running connections for process 10334, application agent
App 16402 stdout:
App 16441 stdout:
App 16464 stdout:
[ 2019-03-27 22:28:05.0320 31726/7f78ba9ff700 age/Cor/App/Poo/AnalyticsCollection.cpp:102 ]: Process (pid=16365, group=agent) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.
```

Is the above behavior due to a race condition between the request handler forwarding the request to the process and the process exiting? Is Passenger designed to handle this scenario? Any workaround / solution for this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we need to run "passenger-config detach-process [PID]" for graceful termination.

> ### Improved process termination mechanism
>
> If you wish to terminate a specific application process -- maybe because it's misbehaving -- then you can do that simply by killing it with the kill command. Unfortunately this method has a few drawbacks:
>
> Any requests which the process was handling will be forcefully aborted, causing error responses to be returned to the clients.
> For a short amount of time, new requests may be routed to that process. These requests will receive error responses.
> In Passenger 5 we've introduced a new, graceful mechanism for terminating application processes: passenger-config detach-process. This command removes the process from the load balancing list, drains all existing requests, then terminates it cleanly.
>
> You can learn more about this tool by running:
>
> passenger-config detach-process --help

Source: https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/03/04/whats-new-in-passenger-5-part-2-better-logging-better-restarting-better-websockets-and-more/